# random checkbox getting checked when scrolling down the list view

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I'm trying to implement `CheckBox` with `OnClickListener`. The examples available are all on `OncheckedchangeListener`.

Once I select one `CheckBox`, and I scroll down the `ListView`, random `CheckBox` are getting checked. no idea why?

```
 holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) v;
                    ClaimList claimList = (ClaimList) checkbox.getTag();
                    claimList.setChecked(checkbox.isChecked());
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `ViewHolder` in `ListView` `Adapter` also need to add `boolean` flag for selected item in getter setter Class

Check this link :[Listview with Checkbox](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-checkbox-example.html)

Comment: i went through the page and manage to solve my problem. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it by overriding this two method in adapter class.

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
          return getCount();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

 return position;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey, I have posted complete code to fix the problem. It worked for me . Do try it once.